# LeanModal implementation with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

How to trigger the LeanModal function when the Send button is clicked in order to inform user whether any of the filling fields are invalid or the form has been successfully submitted.

When Send/Submit button clicked:

- check PHP event handler within the same sheet
- Display the result on the LeanModal

  - If it is successful then text displayed in modal, all fields in the form are empty.
  - If not, then text displayed in modal, the invalid fields in the forms are highlighted.

These are all the files which are related to the contact.php:

1. contact.php (main sheet I've been working on)
2. validate.php (imported to contact.php to validate the form fields)
3. validate.js (functions in this file have been called in contact.php)
4. Leanmodal.js

contact.php:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('a[rel*=leanModal]').leanModal();     
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">

<?if( isset($_POST['send']) && (!validateName($_POST['name']) || !validateSurname($_POST['surname']) || !validateEmail($_POST['email']) || !validateMessage($_POST['message']) || !validateHuman($_POST['human']) ) ):?>  

<div id="error">  
   <ul>  
   <?if(!validateName($_POST['name'])):?>  
      <li><strong>Invalid Name:</strong>Required more than 3 letters!</li>  
   <?endif?>  
   <?if(!validateSurname($_POST['surname'])):?>  
      <li><strong>Invalid Surname:</strong>Required more than 3 letters!</li>  
   <?endif?>  
   <?if(!validateEmail($_POST['email'])):?>  
      <li><strong>Invalid E-mail:</strong>Invalid email-address format!</li>  
   <?endif?>
   <?if(!validateMessage($_POST['message'])):?>  
      <li><strong>Invalid Message:</strong>Required more than 3 letters</li>  
   <?endif?>  
   <?if(!validateHuman($_POST['human'])):?>  
      <li><strong>Answer Incorrect:</strong>Human Validation Failed</li>  
   <?endif?>   
  </ul>  

</div> 

   <?elseif(isset($_POST['send'])):?>  
   <div id="error" class="valid">  
     <ul>  
       <li><strong>Congratulations!</strong></li>  
     </ul>  
   </div>  
   <?endif?>

<form method="post" id="customForm" action="contact.php">
   .
   .
   .
<input id="send" name="send" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validation.js"></script>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is this using jQuery? Also, can you break down your first paragraph a little more? It is not very clear atm.

Comment: Yes LeanModal is jquery plug-in.

Comment: What is your code doing that it shouldn't be doing?  What is your code not doing that it should be doing?  It is unclear from your post what the problem is.

Comment: I need to insert this line 
<a id="go" rel="leanModal" name="error" href="#error" >Dont Want This Text</a> 
somewhere on sheet in order to force the <div id="error"> section to display on the modal window instead of the contact.php above form section but only problem is I need to click the "Send" button first to get the messages displayed on the contact.php and then click on the "Dont Want This Text" link, then finally the error messages will appear on the modal.

Comment: -1 for not following up!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still not entirely clear to me, so I will make some assumptions when answering. I am not familiar with LeanModal, so it may be worth checking the docs for this. (May I suggest you add 'jquery' into your tags, as this feels predominantly like a jquery question?).

It seems you have a PHP-based validation system, but you want to display your errors using JavaScript. You've not mentioned it, but this looks like a candidate for an AJAX op, which is easy in jQuery. You need to capture the click event on your form submission, thus:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#send).click(function() {
        // Do ajax op here

        return false;
    });
});
```

As you can see that is set up instead a DOM ready event; and you'll need to send the contents of your form to the server in order to correctly validate it ([start here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)). I seem to remember there is an excellent forms plugin for jQuery which will do this for you - check it out (or you can obtain the values in a form manually).

The validation result will probably return a JSON answer which will, when received in jQuery, will either show the modal dialogue box or a div that says everything is OK.

If my design assumptions are correct, try that - and let us know how you get on. You may have to do some web-searching, or asking of supplementary questions here, as there is a lot to grapple with :-)